# Easy SpriteKit Contact Detection (Space Shooter Game) Not Wotking Properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, collision-detection, uint32

I'm trying to make a simple Space Shooter game. The contact should happen either between the torpedo and the alien or the shuttle and the alien. The problem is that this second contact (shuttle vs. alien) only happens after the first kind of contact has happend (torpedo vs. alien) and further more they're not always precise. This is a struct created outside the class

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let alien : UInt32 = 1
static let torpedo : UInt32 = 2
static let shuttle : UInt32 = 3 }
```

Shuttle:

```
shuttle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: shuttle.size)
shuttle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.shuttle
shuttle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.alien 
shuttle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false 
shuttle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Torpedo:

```
torpedo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: torpedo.size)
torpedo.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.torpedo
torpedo.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.alien
torpedo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
torpedo.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

Alien:

```
alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: torpedo.size)
alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.alien
alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.torpedo
alien.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
alien.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

Finally, here's my contact code:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.alien) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.torpedo)) ||
    ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.torpedo) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.alien)) {
        self.contactWithTorpedo(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, torpedo: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.shuttle) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.alien)) {
            self.contactWithShuttle(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, shuttle: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
}


func contactWithTorpedo (alien: SKSpriteNode, torpedo : SKSpriteNode) {
    alien.removeFromParent()
    torpedo.removeFromParent()
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "score: " + "\(score)"
}

func contactWithShuttle (alien:SKSpriteNode, shuttle:SKSpriteNode) {
    alien.removeFromParent()
    shuttle.removeFromParent()

    self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())

}
```

I'm not really sure where the problem is, plus I've seen a couple of tutorials do the same. I don't know if it's relevant by the way, but this is not an iOS game but an OSX. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Jules - are you saying that *no* contacts between a shuttle and an alien are recognised until there has been a contact between a torpedo and an alien?

Comment: The possible problem with this code is that if there was a contact between a  shuttle and an alien, but the SKPhysicscontact passed to didBeginContact had firstBody == alien and secondBody == shuttle, your self.collisionWithShuttle wouldn't get called due to the if...then statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it less confusing to restructure your `didBeginContact` as follows, as this avoids the firstBody/secondbody stuff and the complicated `if...then` conditions to see what has contacted what:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case PhysicsCategory.alien | PhysicsCategory.torpedo:
       // alien and torpedo have contacted
       contact.bodyA.removeFromParent()
       contact.bodyB.removeFromParent()
       score += 1
       scoreLabel.text = "score: " + "\(score)"

    case PhysicsCategory.alien | PhysicsCategory.shuttle:
       // alien and shuttle have contacted
       contact.bodyA.removeFromParent()
       contact.bodyB.removeFromParent()

       self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())

    default :
        //Some other contact has occurred
        print("Some other contact")
    }
}
```

You can just add as many `PhysicsCategory.enemy | PhysicsCategory.player` cases as you need for all the contacts that you have to take action for in your game. Code each potential contact individually and you won't loose yourself in if...then...else.

if you do need to reference only one of the nodes involved in a contact, (e.g. to remove the player after an enemy hits it), you can do it like this:

```
let playerNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.player ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
playernode.removefromParent
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't seem to be "recognizing" the collisions: when the bodies collide they just move each other, just like no function was being called. Anyhow your way seems much cleaner and easier to manage. Can you help any further? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jules - Can you add the line print("Contact detected") as the first line of didBeginContact just to see if any contacts are being recognised.

Comment: Physics bodies moving each other when they collide has nothing to do with contact detection for the 'didBeginContact'/'didEndContact' functions. There is no code in your program (other than the setting of the categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask) for collisions, only contacts.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do confuse collisions and contacts. I will have to read the documenations once again. I also changed the mistakes you were toalking about inthe question's code. By the way, thank you so much for your help, this now works perfectly! I do prefer it this way. Thank you once again for you patience.

Comment: @Jules - you're welcome. Helping fix other user's problems also helps my understanding of how things work and when I started with SpriteKit (about a month ago) I couldn't work out the difference between a contact and a collision :-) Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read the the docs about [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/).

> Every physics body in a scene can be assigned to up to 32 different categories, each corresponding to a bit in the bit mask. You define the mask values used in your game. In conjunction with the collisionBitMask and contactTestBitMask properties, you define which physics bodies interact with each other and when your game is notified of these interactions

First of all I would change the PhysicsCategory to

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let alien : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let torpedo : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let shuttle : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3 
}
```

Then

```
alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.torpedo | PhysicsCategory.shuttle
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had read the documentation before but it didn't really help me much (I've started using SpriteKit only yesterday). I've tried your way but I still get the same problem: the collision between the shuttle and the alien only happens after I've destroyed an alien with a torpedo. Do you have any other ideas? Even just a link to a tutorial or other documentation you know would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

So I've actually managed to solve my problem yesterday. I'm posting the updated code in case it could help someone.
Outside the class:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let player : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
static let bullet : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let enemy : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2}
```

And then, after applying the phyics to each sprite as i wrote before, inside the class:

```
    //Contact with bullet
func contactWithBullet(enemy : SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode) {
    enemy.removeFromParent()
    bullet.removeFromParent()
    score += 1
    updateLabels()
}

//contact with player
func contactWithPlayer(player : SKSpriteNode, enemy : SKSpriteNode) {
    enemy.removeFromParent()
    lives -= 1
    updateLabels() //another function that changes the score and lives labels
}
//CONTACT DETECTION
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) {
        contactWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        checkScore()
        enemiesInWave -= 1
    } else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.player || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.player && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) {
        contactWithPlayer(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, enemy: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        checkLives()
        enemiesInWave -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't get confused between contacts & collisions - you've named your functions that get called when there are contacts as 'collisionWith...' which is a bit confusing.