# SKSpritenodes not creating contact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 9 SKSpritenodes that i want to detect contact with another SKSpritenode. I set the ContactTestBitMask to make contact but the code in the did begin contact was never called.

```
 for i in (0...8){


        squares[i].node.position = positions[i]
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physics[i]
        squares[i].node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: squares[i].node.size )
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Circle
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        squares[i].node.color = squares[i].startColor
        squares[i].node.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        squares[i].node.size = CGSize(width: squareUnit, height: squareUnit)



    }
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code. What debugging have you done?

Comment: At least one body has to be dynamic... your squares and circles are both static.

Comment: but I'm not testing collision

Comment: and i posted all my code because i didn't know what could be the problem so if you saw everything you could find it but if i didn't you might not

Comment: thank you that worked. the game now stopped at the breakpoint in did begin contact

Comment: also, is there something wrong with this :     if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Circle && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physics[i] || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physics[i] && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Circle    :   because i put a breakpoint after that and nothing happens

Comment: @Repardeimaj It doesn't matter if you are not *testing* collisions... Collisions won't work if two bodies are static. Same goes for contacts. About your issue... Personally I prefer to handle contacts this way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36717489/3402095.

Comment: i changed it to:             switch contactMask {
            case PhysicsCategory.Circle | physics[i]:
                
                
                changeColor(i:i)
                circle.color = .red
                circle.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
            default: print("otherContact")
            }       :but it still doesn't work

Comment: do you think it has something to do with my physics array

Comment: @Repardeimaj Use breakpoints. See what is bodyA and what is bodyB and try to figure out why there is no contact/collision (inspect contact, collision and category bit masks).

Comment: @Repardeimaj Also in your `createSquares()` method, put this line : `squares[i].node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physics[i]` after this line: `squares[i].node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: squares[i].node.size )`. Your code currently *works* because of optional chaining, so there is no crash (everything fails gracefully), but still, your physics body `categoryBitMask` is not set because the body was nil at the time you were trying to configure it.

Comment: I have fixed my question to fit the rules in help center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your problem would be to move this line (in `createSquares()` method):

```
squares[i].node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physics[i]
```

after physicsBody initialization, which happens here:

```
squares[i].node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: squares[i].node.size )
```

And to handle contacts like this:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case PhysicsCategory.Circle | PhysicsCategory.square1:


        print("square 1")
    case PhysicsCategory.Circle | PhysicsCategory.square2:


        print("square 2")
    case PhysicsCategory.Circle | PhysicsCategory.square3:


        print("square 3")
    case PhysicsCategory.Circle | PhysicsCategory.square4:


        print("square 4")


   // and so on ...

    default :
        //Some other contact has occurred
        print("Some other contact")
    }


}
```